# How to get SlowCheetah to transform SQL files

Tags: sql, visual-studio, slowcheetah

The [Microsoft Slowcheetah website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) states

> This package allows you to automatically transform your app.config (or any file) when you press F5 in Visual Studio.

I have a SQL Server VS solution which requires configuration dependent users and logins. Slowcheetah would be a good solution if I can figure out what the transform file should look like.

For example I would like the statement

```
CREATE LOGIN [DEVDOMAIN\ReadonlyUser] FROM WINDOWS DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyDb_Dev;
```

Transformed to

```
CREATE LOGIN [TESTDOMAIN\ReadonlyUser] FROM WINDOWS DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyDb_Uat;
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Where did you see the "any file" quote exactly? https://github.com/microsoft/slow-cheetah#supported-file-types suggests it only supports XML and JSON files

Comment: @ADyson [SlowCheetah - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) says *This package allows you to automatically transform your app.config (or any file) when you press F5 in Visual Studio.*

Comment: @AlwaysLearning hmm, looks like a bit of poor wording to me. The strapline part also says "Transform xml and json files at build time". All the examples given relate to config files as well.

Comment: I edited my post to include a link

Comment: @HughJones are you hoping to transform SQL scripts? Or just some associated XML/JSON config files? It would be good to have an example of the input, and the required output.

Comment: I'm thinking they meant to say "(or any XML file)".

Comment: @ADyson - yes .sql scripts. My use case is CREATE USER and CREATE LOGIN scripts; AD User accounts are needed for develop, test, uat and production builds and in our environment the domains are separated.  I would also need a postdeployment script to add the appropriate user to a role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SlowCheetah](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah) currently only supports using [XML Document Transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)) on XML files or [JSON Document Transforms](https://github.com/Microsoft/json-document-transforms/wiki) on JSON files.

If you can get your user data into one of those format you'll be set, otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

So it is not possible as far as anyone can tell.  I also had no luck trying to get files to load into the projects according to which build configuration had been selected.  This seems to be a feature of VS Sql Projects.

The solution I came up with in the end was to

i)   Manually edit the .sqlproj (unload the project, right-click, select 'edit') adding in

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None include="dbo\Security\users\ReadonlyUser\DEV_Login.sql"  
  <None include="dbo\Security\users\ReadonlyUser\UAT_Login.sql"
  <!-- et cetera -->
</ItemGroup>
```

ii)  add another itemgroup

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Build include="dbo\Security\users\ReadonlyUser_Login.sql"   
</ItemGroup>
```

iii) Reload the project and add a Build event (Pre-build event command line)

```
Copy $(ProjectDir)\dbo\Security\users\ReadonlyUser\$(Configuration)_Login.sql $(ProjectDir)\dbo\Security\users\ReadonlyUser_Login.sql
```